# How to find child images on Docker Hub / GitHub

Tags: docker, github, dockerhub, docker-cloud

As a contributor to a popular Docker base image ([baseimage-docker](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker)), I'd like to search for all public images which are child images of this image.

Is there any way to do this, either via Docker Hub/Cloud's API, or via a GitHub code search?

In GitHub I'd be looking for "Dockerfile"-s, which contain the line (+ optional version strings):

```
FROM phusion/baseimage
```

For example, elk-docker has this file: https://github.com/spujadas/elk-docker/blob/master/Dockerfile#L10

I tried putting this line in GitHub's search but it barely returned any results, with elk-docker notably missing.